# Error after updating from Ubuntu 10.04 to Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, wubi, updates

Upon rebooting after updating from Ubuntu 10.04 to Ubuntu 10.10 (with wubi), the screen displayed the following error message:

> "error "prefix" not found"

After that, the screen displayed a single flashing line. What should I do to get Ubuntu working again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research and folowing the lead of the OP http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11611236#post11611236 the conclusion to question was using Boot-Repair

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

[image]